# How to get error stack in window.onerror with errors

Tags: javascript

How to get error stack in `window.onerror` ?

The below error has an error stack, but in `onerror` the error is `null` and all the rest of the arguments are not specified?

Actually all javascript errors ends up like this and in any browser. What am I missing/doing wrong?

I'm using
`Google Chrome Version 109.0.5414.75 (Officiel version) (64-bit)`

error in browser console

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: dkdkdk is not defined
    at Object.input_dynamic (Trait_module_document_posts-2.js:386:16)
    at Document_posts-2.js:434:18
    at append (Module-2.js:417:13)
    at Object.append (Module-2.js:327:4)
    ...
```

method

```
window.onerror = function(msg, file, line, column, error){
    console.log(msg, file, line, column, error);
};
```

output

```
Script error.  0 0 null
```

## update

It's implemented in a file like this `<script src="//url/js/init.js"></script>`

init.js

```
'use strict';

window.onerror = function(msg, file, line, column, error){
    $.get(APIURL+'action/error_js', {
        msg: msg,
        file: file || '',
        url: window.location.href,
        line: line,
        stack: error?.stack || ''
    });
};
    
...
```

Comment: I have tested the code using the online JavaScript playground and made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fLz6a8yw/) example. It should work accordingly, where are you running this script, where in the stack have you placed the window.error handler?

Comment: Which environment and browser are you trying this in?

Comment: have updated my question.. I use Chrome

Comment: @clarkk Which Chrome? “Chrome” is a browser vendor, not a specific browser. Which version?

Comment: You have placed your error handler inside the jQuery function. Which means, the event handler will only catch error that's made within the scope. If you put it on top of your file, meaning outside the jQuery function and trigger an error with or outside the scope, the event handler runs as normal.

Comment: @node_modules It doesn't care about the scope because it's added on the window object..

Comment: @SebastianSimon Google Chrome Version 109.0.5414.75 (Officiel version) (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. It happens because of the JS files is located on another domain (CORS)

Solution is found here
https://sentry.io/answers/script-error/